# Any significant performance cost to using BlendState.Premultiplied?

Tags: xna, textures

Normally I guess you'd use BlendState.AlphaBlend because normally when you load your textures through the pipeline they're already premultiplied. However, if you're loading textures at runtime from PNGs or some such, you have to loop through the pixels and premultiply them, which can take a long time if you've got a lot of textures to load.

So it looks (haven't tried it) like using BlendState.NonPremultiplied instead of BlendState.AlphaBlend should handle non-premultiplied textures and produce the same visual result, without all the startup costs. I have to wonder if there's a non-obvious cost to doing this, like a huge drop in performance or something. Anyone know?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There shouldn't be any performance cost to different blend modes.  All of them are implemented in hardware and moreover, the difference between them is just which numbers get plugged into a standard blending formula.

Comment: (OT: today I learned that what XNA calls `BlendState.AlphaBlend` is what the rest of the world would call "premultiplied", and their `BlendState.NonPremultiplied` is what the rest of the world calls "alpha blending"...I guess XNA wants premultiplied to be the standard mode, which is fine, but needlessly confusing to change the terminology around. Ugh.)

Comment: I just have this vague feeling of dread that if I go down that path, I'll discover somewhere way way WAY down the road that there's ONE ESSENTIAL THING that you can't do that way. But I'm not cynical. Or bitter. :-)

Comment: +1, but if anything it may be (slightly, only slightly) faster as the driver may be able to detect and skip a multiplication by 1.